# The problem of using OpenCV to do crack detection

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

src = cv.imread("Image set/Positive/00010.jpg")
cv.imshow("input", src)

gray = cv.cvtColor(src, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, binary = cv.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv.THRESH_OTSU)

se = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_RECT, (10, 10), (-1, -1))
binary = cv.morphologyEx(binary, cv.MORPH_OPEN, se)
cv.imshow("binary", binary)

contours,hierachy=cv.findContours(binary,cv.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
height, width = src.shape[:2]
for c in range(len(contours)):
    x, y, w, h = cv.boundingRect(contours[c])
    area = cv.contourArea(contours[c])
    if h > (height//2):
        continue
    if area < 150:
        continue
    cv.rectangle(src, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 0, 255), 1, 8, 0)
    cv.drawContours(src, contours, c, (0, 255, 0), 1, 8)

cv.imshow("result", src)
cv.imwrite("result.jpg", src)

cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Above is the code I wrote, I used OpenCV to try to detect the cracks, but I only detect part of the cracks instead of all the cracks. I am not sure how to solve this problem.

[image][image]

But in the other case, the detection performance is perfect
[image]

Comment: That's pretty danged good.  If you're looking for defects, this would certainly point you to the right area.  The areas between those regions are only subtly different from the background.

Comment: That's an impressive result already. Image recognition is never going to be perfect, and you've already got an excellent program here, based on that image you've shown.

Comment: Whether this can be better optimized, so that the results of cracks can be connected？

Comment: after your current result, compute the min and max intensity values of your crack mask. After that, use the thresholding again (this time with threshold value according the computed values instead of OTSU) without morphological operator post-processing.